Determining the radius of convergence of the power series with alteranting terms
Consider the power series
[
$\sum a_n z^n $
]
where
[
$a_n$ =
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\ 
\frac{1}{2^n} & \text{if } n \text{ is odd} 
\end{cases}
]
Finding the Radius of Convergence:
How do I find the radius of convergence ( R ) using the formula involving the limit supremum, specifically:
[
$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$
]
Could you walk me through the calculation of $( \limsup |a_n|^{1/n} )$ based on the definitions of $( a_n )?$
Thanking you

My attempt: $( \lim |a_n|^{1/n} )$ does not exist:}

For even ( $n$ ), ( $|a_n| = 1$ ) and thus ( $|a_n|^{1/n} = 1^{1/n} = 1$ ).
For odd ($ n$ ), ( $|a_n| = \frac{1}{2^n}$ ) and thus ($ |a_n|^{1/n} = \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{1/n} = \frac{1}{(2^n)^{1/n}} $).
As ( $n \to \infty$ ), Therefore, the sequence $|a_n|^{1/n}$ oscillates between values converging to ($ 1$ ) and $1/2$ and does not settle to a single limit.




When this happens the $\limsup $ is simply the greatest of the two limits.
So the radius of convergence is $1.$
You can look up the notions of $\limsup $ and $\liminf,$ which are slightly tricky. It should be the sup or inf of the limit points,  ims.

The way I like to think of $\limsup_n x_n$ is as the limit of future suprema, i.e.
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n := \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{N \ge n} x_N
$$
So, for the sequence $x_n := |a_n|^{1/n}$, we consider that, no matter what $N$ is, $\sup_{N \ge n} |a_n|^{1/n}=1$, because there will always be some larger even number for which $|a_n|^{1/n}=1$, while $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is vanishingly small (and certainly smaller than $1$).
This makes the limit supremum and in turn the radius of convergence easy to deduce.

A subsequence of $(\sqrt[n]{|a_n|})$ converges to $1$ and no subsequence can converge to something larger than $1$, because $1$ is an (essential) upper bound.
Thus the limes superior is $1$.
You can confirm this by noting that if
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}z^n\qquad g(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^n}{2^n}
$$
the radius of convergence of the first series is $1$ and of the second series is $2$. Since
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n=f(z^2)+zg(z^2),
$$
the radius of convergence is the smaller of the radii of the summands.
